# Требуется не оставлять висячие предлоги в конце стоки. Что можно улучшить в решении?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть набор строк на русском языке (utf-8). Кроме русских слов строки могут содержать цифры, аббревиатуры, сокращения и единицы измерения. Строки могут быть длинными, из-за чего при выводе могут переносится на следующую строку.

Пример данных:
`корова с теленком породы the black angus весят в сумме 500 кг`

Требуется, чтобы переносы строк не оставляли висячие предлоги, когда предлог в конце строки, потом перенос, потом слово которое он предваряет.

Я решил это так:

```
$text = preg_replace('/\x20([а-яА-ЯёЁ]{2,6})\x20/m', ' \\1&nbsp;', $text);
```

Однако очевидно что решение неидеально. Как улучшить?

---

**UPDATE 04.02.2019**

Заметил, что в большинстве случаев предлог короче слова следующего за ним. Т.е. нужно сравнить длины всех слов и при увеличении длины следующего элемента заменять пробел на неразрывный. Так же проверяется чтобы предлоги и слова за ними состояли из русских букв.

```
$text = 'корова с теленком породы the black angus весят в сумме 500 кг';
$textarr = explode(' ', $text);
foreach($textarr as $key => $str) {
    if(isset($textarr[$key+1]) &&
      (mb_strlen($textarr[$key]) < 6) &&
      (preg_match('/(^|\s)[а-яА-ЯёЁ]{1,}/', $str)) &&
      (mb_strlen($textarr[$key+1])) > mb_strlen($str) &&
      (preg_match('/(^|\s)[а-яА-ЯёЁ]{2,}/', $textarr[$key+1])))
          $textarr[$key] .= '&nbsp;';
}
$text = implode(' ', $textarr);
$text = str_replace('&nbsp; ','&nbsp;', $text);
```

Можно ли уменьшить количество кода?

Answer (score 1):

Например, перечислить предлоги:

```
$text = preg_replace('/\x20([а|в|по|под|за|с|без|у|на|при|к|перед|после])\x20/m', ' \\1&nbsp;', $text);
```

Comment: Не согласен что это лучше, т.к. есть вариант не указать какой-нибудь предлог, пример у вас нет "пред", "над"... Ну в общем вот https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F:%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8

Comment: Конечно же, этот вариант лучше. Он не пропускает предлоги из одной буквы ("с", "к", "в" и т.д.), в отличие от вашего, а так же слова из 2-6 букв, которые предлогами не являются. Недостающие предлоги легко добавить. Я, кстати, и не говорил, что перечислил все предлоги.

Comment: Русские буквы в uft-8 занимают 2 байта. Т.ч. пропуска однобуквенных предлогов в моем варианте нет. Перейдите по ссылке из комментария, там больше сотни предлогов. Хотя конечно есть довольно специфические, которые никогда не будут использованы в реальности.

Comment: Не знаю, как в php, но в других языках в скобках ``{}`` указывается количество повторений того, что перед этим, а не байт. Перед этим у вас указаны буквы.

Comment: В конечном итоге это не принципиально. Спасибо за ваш совет.